# Route Model binding not working with POST

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5.4, model-binding

I have two HTTP methods for the same route as shown below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['user.ownership']], function () {
   Route::get('users/{user}/folders/{folder}', 'FileController@listUserFolder');
   Route::post('users/{user}/folders/{folder}/folders', 'FileController@createFolder');
});
```

The problem is that when the request hits the middleware `user.ownership` the route model binding works for the GET request but does not work for the POST. It makes no sense to me.

The middleware checks if the user owns the resource (in this case a folder). The problem shows up when I try to get the `Folder` model. In one case it returns the model but in the other it just returns the id. Here's the middleware code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckIfUserOwnsResource
{
    /**
     * Comprueba si el recurso solicitado pertenece
     * al usuario que lo solicita.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $file = $request->folder;

        $fileOwner = $file->account;
        $fileApplicant = $user->account;

        if($fileOwner != $fileApplicant) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'El recurso no le pertenece',
            ], 403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The POST route creates a subfolder inside the folder passed.

Comment: I’m a bit confused. When do you have `{folder}` in your POST route if a user’s _creating_ a folder? The folder doesn’t exist if the user’s creating it?

Comment: No, it creates a subfolder inside that `{folder}`. Originally the route was `users/{user}/folders/{folder}/folders` but I renamed it to check if that had something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the parameter using:

```php
$this->route('parameterName');
```

or

```php
$request->route('parameterName');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are passing parameters into route then it could not be a POST request its get its called urlencoded format.

If you dont know about it simply use any keyword instead of post and get
laravel set it to appropriate check the manual first [route methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

use `any` method like this,

```
Route::any('users/{user}/folders/{folder}', 'FileController@listUserFolder');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Will it work if I code another route like 

`Route::delete('users/{user}/folders/{folder}', 'FileController@deleteFolder');` ??

Comment: just try it, its amazing no need to know about what parameter i have to send in get or post.

Comment: and if you want to pass slugs into route then you have to go with `get` or `any` post accepts only form data.

Comment: This is not the issue, and you should _not_ be using `any` routes.

Comment: @MartinBean do you think is it valid???
Route::post('users/{user}/folders/{folder}/folders', 'FileController@createFolder');

Passing a slug with post request??

Comment: @MartinBean And why we can not use `any` first see the manual. laravel manual mentioned that the `any` route can handle get post put delete all the requests, I have used also.
if you have any better way then `teach us`

Comment: @Rits The “better way” is to use a resource controller that responds to specific requests with specific actions, and not just have some generic route that responds to any HTTP method, as a controller action handling those requests is bound to full of horrible, conditional logic. RE: it being documented, remember: Just because you _can_ doesn’t mean you _should_.

Comment: @Rits Also, I did “teach”: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/laravel-5-essentials

Comment: @MartinBean okay fine you should go for resource, i have used any and everything is working perfect i have no issue with this.
its all yours what you want to use.

Comment: @Rits I already did in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092015/route-model-binding-not-working-with-post/48092666?noredirect=1#comment83162166_48092666

Comment: @MartinBean oh thats why we can not use `any` method but realy did not understand.  but i would like to know if any case `resource` fails what should you use for this route `Route::post('users/{user}/folders/{folder}/folders', 'FileController@createFolder');` ???

Comment: @Rits What do you mean, “if any case resource fails”? `resource` just registers all the routes need for CRUD actions for a particular model.

Comment: yeah but in some cases might be it fails

Comment: @MartinBean then what should i do??

Comment: @Rits What would “fail”? It’s just a bunch of routes!

Comment: yeah i know about that but i am telling about posibilities @MartinBean

Comment: @Rits I really don’t understand what you mean.